# How to return awaitable (Task?) that waits for an event in Dispatcher Thread

Tags: wpf, concurrency, async-await, task-parallel-library, dispatcher

I have threads:

1. UI thread with Dispatcher loop
2. background thread that listens for messages in a queuing framework.

when a message is received, an event is fired in the background thread:

```
messageReceiver.Received += (sender, args) => ...
```

In UI thread I would like to await a message, something like this:

```
void ButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    await NextMessage(); //should return when messageReceiver.Received is fired
}
```

**How to implement awaitable NextMessage method, so it does not create new thread each time?**

There is `SemaphoreSlim` class where I can await WaitAsync, but is seems to create new thread that is blocked until SemaphoreSlim is released.

Maybe `TaskCompletionSource` is the way to go? Which TaskCreationOption should I use then?

Comment: `SemaphoreSlim` does not create a thread.

Comment: So what's the difference between `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` and `TaskCompletionSource.Task`?

Comment: `TaskCompletionSource` is a one-time notification. `SemaphoreSlim` can be reused. There are other differences, but that's the one most applicable to this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned the `TaskCompletionSource` and that is what I believe you need here. You'd tether it to the `.Received` event like so:

```
static Task<IEnumerable<Message>> FromEvent(Receiver messageReceiver)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IEnumerable<Message>>();

    EventHandler<IEnumerable<Message>> handler = null;
    handler = (o, e) =>
        {
            messageReceiver.Received -= handler;
            tcs.SetResult(e.Messages);
        };
    messageReceiver.Received += handler;

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Then you could await it like this:

```
// Having the async keyword is fine here since this is an event handler 
async void ButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    var messages = await FromEvent(messageReceiver);
}
```

Comment: btw, this creates memory leak, doesn't it?

Comment: I've ended up using RX: `await ObservableFromReceivedEvent(messageReceiver).FirstAsync(e => e.MessageId == this.MessageId)`